# Pandas create datetime column from date and integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 3 columns as per below:

df:

```
day         min_from  value
2012-10-12    0        0.34
2012-10-12    30       0.36
2012-10-12    60       0.56
```

df.dtypes

```
min_from               int64
day                    datetime64[ns]
value                  float64
```

I am trying to create the following

```
date                   value
2012-10-12 00:00:00    0.34
2012-10-12 00:30:00    0.36
2012-10-12 00:60:00    0.56
```

I tried:

```
def create_dt(row):
    return str(df['day'])+ ' '+ str(timedelta(minutes=df['min_from']))

df['date_time'] = df.apply(create_dt, axis=1)
```

But get the following error when I apply create_dt:

```
TypeError: ('unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: Series', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `day` column is in datetime format, you can add a `Timedelta` like this, avoiding the call to `apply` (which can be slow):

```
# In case day is not datetime yet:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['min_from'],unit='m')

# Otherwise
df['date'] = df['day'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['min_from'],unit='m')

>>> df
         day  min_from  value                 date
0 2012-10-12         0   0.34  2012-10-12 00:00:00
1 2012-10-12        30   0.36  2012-10-12 00:30:00
2 2012-10-12        60   0.56  2012-10-12 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import timedelta

df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.day + timedelta(minute=row.min_from), axis=1)
```

Will create a `date` column in your `DataFrame` with minutes